# Searching whether data in one table exists in another table using full text search SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find out whether I can do the following using joins instead of looping through each record.

```
Table1
------------
LastName
FirstName

Table2
-------------
UniqueId
LastName  (full text indexed)
FirstName (full text indexed)
```

for each record in table1, I am trying to find out if there are any matching records in table2.

Thanks,
sridhar

Comment: in the future post more details liek what you are joining on!

Comment: JonH - I am not sure what other details I need to post. I specified in the subject that I need a solution using full text search. And I have provided table structures and explained what I needed. If it is a straight join why would I mention "full text indexed" next to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info like what you are joining on.
If you are joining based on those fields you could do:

```
SELECT Table2.LastName, Table2.FirstName
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 t ON t.FirstName=Table2.FirstName
AND t.LastName = Table2.LastName
```

This should return all rows where data matches up in both tables.

Is this waht you need?

**EDIT PORTION**

If you want that try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_2 t2 INNER JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.lastname LIKE t1.lastname + '%'
```

Modify to fit your needs.

Comment: No that's not what I want. If we do the above it will only return the exact matches. I want to do something like "where LastName in Table2 is like LastName in Table1"

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table_2 t2 INNER JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.lastname LIKE t1.lastname + '%'

Comment: I am trying to use full text querying capabilities. I don't want to use "LIKE" since it is not efficient on large number of records.